# ask FB api graph user info with access_token from my API OAuthException

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I try to get user info from my API to facebook API graph from an access_token provide by clients app, but I keep getting this error

```
{
 "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "***********"
 }
}
```

here is a drawing to explain my structure:

[image]

the weird thing if I do a simple: 
`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**&field=email`

I have a valid json answer with the data.

BUT when I ask from my API I get the that i showed error above...
(in the futur I want to check if we have a user in the DB with the same email as a facebook account to avoid double account conflict)

I do it like this :

```
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");

/**
 * getJSON:  REST get request returning JSON object(s)
 * @param options: http options object
 * @param callback: callback to pass the results JSON object(s) back
 */
function getJSON(options, onResult)
{
    console.log("rest::getJSON");

    var port = options.port == 443 ? https : http;
    var req = port.request(options, function(res)
    {
        var output = '';
        console.log(options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var obj = JSON.parse(output);
            onResult(res.statusCode, obj);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
  //      res.send('error: ' + err.message);
    console.log(err.message + '\n');
    return(err);
    });

     req.end();
};

/*////////////////////////////
//                          //
//  Function /signup route  //
//                          //
*/////////////////////////////

// router.post('/signup-fb', signup-fb)
exports.signupFb = async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;

  console.log('login fb', data)

  if (!data.fbToken) {
      res.status(404);
      res.json({success: false, message: "Fb token is blank"});
      res.end();
      return
  }

  var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v2.6/me/',
    method: 'GET',
    body: {'access_token': data.fbToken,
            'fields': 'id,name,email'}
  };
  const tmp = await getJSON(options, function(statusCode, result) {
    // I could work with the result html/json here.  I could also just return it
    console.log(tmp);
    console.log("onResult: (" + statusCode + ")" + JSON.stringify(result));
    res.statusCode = statusCode;
    res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: You are checking `data.fbToken`, but then you are using `data.access_token` ...?

Comment: I did a mistake when I put my code here on Stackoverflow nothing change...

Comment: Not sure if you should actually put that inside `body` - POST requests do have a body, but this is a GET ... Either specify the query string separately, or append it to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER

the answer is in the comment.

To request the API Graph I had to append the variables of the body in the path like this:

```
var options = {
   host: 'graph.facebook.com',
   port: 443,
   path: '/v2.6/me/?access_token='+data.fbToken+'&fields=id,name,email',
   method: 'GET'
};
```